# How do I code to display every change in data in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has data in below format.

```
| ID  |        DateTime       | Value |
| 1   | 2019-08-12 05:07:25   |   0   |
| 2   | 2019-08-12 05:08:25   |   1   |
| 3   | 2019-08-12 05:09:25   |   1   |
| 4   | 2019-08-12 05:10:25   |   1   |
| 5   | 2019-08-12 05:11:25   |   0   |
| 6   | 2019-08-12 05:12:25   |   0   |
| 7   | 2019-08-12 05:13:25   |   0   |
| 8   | 2019-08-12 05:14:25   |   1   |
| 9   | 2019-08-12 05:15:25   |   1   |
|10   | 2019-08-12 05:16:25   |   0   |
```

From the above table i need to display the result as

```
Record NO |      Start Time      |        Stop Time    |
   1      | 2019-08-12 05:08:25  | 2019-08-12 05:11:25 |
   2      | 2019-08-12 05:14:25  | 2019-08-12 05:16:25 |
```

For record 1 start time is 1st table id # 2 and stop time is id 5.
For record 2 start time is 1st table id # 8 and stop time is id 10.

Comment: May I know the logic in getting the start time and end time?

Comment: @MuhammedShihabudeenLabbaA seems like the start time begins on the first 1 in `Value` and ends on next 0

Comment: It is simply change of value from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0. Change from 0 to 1 is a start time and  next change from 1 to 0 is the stop time. This is one record. The next record again follows the same logic

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far?  Even just ordering the table by time and in PHP checking for a change of value?

Comment: @NeigelRen, it isn't a problem to get the records from the DB to display the data  or just ordering. My issue is in creating a new resultant table where every change is recorded as a start and stop. I had implemented  logic where in every time a new data is inserted into the First table, it takes the last record and compares the same with a current value and see if there is a change and stores this information into a new table. This works fine. But now I face an issue as the data doesn't come to server int he order shown in the table. Data comes at random time.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: MySql version 5.7

Comment: If the order of data in the first table is stable, I can try.

Comment: No, the data from the first table doesn't come in the same order shown. It changes.

Comment: @MuhammedShihabudeenLabbaA It might be 2019-08-12 05:09:25 coming first followed by 2019-08-12 05:08:25  and then 2019-08-12 05:15:25. Only by end of day the table will be completed with all the data.

Comment: I hope you need to enter the value to the second table by the end of the day after table 1 is filled with data. Am I right?

Comment: @NeigelRen Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @NeigelRen I do not need the code. I can code myself. I just need the logic that can be applied.

Comment: @MuhammedShihabudeenLabbaA Do you have any logic that could work?

Comment: If the case is like that I explained, you can run a cron job daily after the table 1 is filled with data. In the cron job, you need to fetch the data from table 1 order by DateTime. Then, you need to loop through each record and using a condition you can fill

Comment: foreach($records as $record) {
    $current_value = $record->value;
    if($previous_value == 0 && $current_value == 1) {
        $start_time = $record->DateTime;
    }
    if($previous_value == 1 && $current_value == 0) {
        $end_time = $record->DateTime;
    }
    $previous_value = $current_value;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your comment: "[Consider a situation where I need to access the available data, how could I do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669875/how-do-i-code-to-display-every-change-in-data-in-a-mysql-database#comment101788552_57670566)"

One way is use a combination of `LEFT JOIN` and Derived Tables (subqueries). In the first subquery, we determine the `EndTime` for every record whose `Value = 1`.

Now, due to issue of consecutive records having `Value = 1`, we filter it out further in outer query, by selecting minimum of them, based on a group of `EndTime`.

**Query**

```
SELECT Min(dt.`starttime`) AS `StartTime`,
       dt.`endtime`
FROM   (SELECT t1.`datetime`      AS `StartTime`,
               Min(t2.`datetime`) AS `EndTime`
        FROM   your_table_name AS t1
               LEFT JOIN your_table_name AS t2
                      ON t2.`datetime` > t1.`datetime`
                         AND t2.`value` = 0
        WHERE  t1.`value` = 1
        GROUP  BY t1.`datetime`) AS dt
GROUP  BY dt.`endtime`;

| StartTime           | endtime             |
| ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 2019-08-12 05:08:25 | 2019-08-12 05:11:25 |
| 2019-08-12 05:14:25 | 2019-08-12 05:16:25 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aSXposJssJdTqpSCTDXn1P/0)

Answer (score 1):

If the case is like that I explained, you can run a cron job daily after the table 1 is filled with data. In the cron job, you need to fetch the data from table 1 order by DateTime.

```
foreach($records as $record) {
    $current_value = $record->value;
    if($previous_value == 0 && $current_value == 1) {
        $start_time = $record->DateTime;
    }
    if($previous_value == 1 && $current_value == 0) {
        $end_time = $record->DateTime;
    }
    $previous_value = $current_value;
}
```

Comment: This can be a solution. Consider a situation where I need to access the available data, how could I do that?